# How can I use RelativeTimeFormat.formatToParts?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I want to be able to list a period of time on my website. Something like "Page generation time: 2 seconds". Being aware of internationalisation, I naturally want to do this in the most locale-aware way possible.

The [relative time format API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RelativeTimeFormat) sounds *perfect* for this, only it constructs strings like "in 2 seconds" or "2 seconds ago". The [formatToParts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RelativeTimeFormat/formatToParts) function splits the string up nicely for me, but it labels both "seconds" and "in/ago" as "literal", with no indication which is which.

I'm pretty sure language differences mean I can't rely on the "in" equivalent being the first word... or even just one word. Is there any way to use formatToParts to extract any part of the string other than the number? (Which I could get anyway with NumberFormat?)

Comment: You can't take a string, "chop" something, and hope for a good result. formatToParts was created so that you can format (as in "css") the various parts.There might be no stand-alone word matching the "in" word, or removing that (if there is one) might leave you with a linguistically correct result.

Comment: In some languages the words itself changes to convey the "in foo" or "the foo" or "every foo" concepts, without a standalone article. Also the translation is context dependent. For instance in Russian "June" is has different forms for "June 25, 2019" vs "June 2019" ("25 июня 2010 г." vs "июнь 2019 г."). So you can't formatToParts and remove the day, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not help everyone, but for me personally I was able to solve this use-case not with the relative time format API, but with the number format API.

```js
const secondsToString = Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.languages, {
  style: "unit",
  unit: "second",
  unitDisplay: "long"
}).format;
console.log(secondsToString(2.42));
```